# Resize component logic

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to Java. I want to implement resize event in JavaFX but my issue is more like logic problem.

```
bp.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {

                if (me.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY) && me.getClickCount() % 1 == 0) {

                    bp.setPrefSize(480, 280);
                    bp.setMaxSize(480, 280);

                }

                if (me.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY) && me.getClickCount() % 2 == 0) {
                    bp.setPrefSize(320, 180);
                    bp.setMaxSize(320, 180);

                }
            }
        });
```

My my code when I click one with the mouse over the `bp` componet the size is expanded. When I double click the component is shrink again to normal size.

I want to edit the code this way: I want to click on the component once end expand it. When I click once again to shrink back the component. Can you tell me how I need to modify the logic into my code?

Comment: `n % 1` is always `0`.

Comment: (n % 1) will be 0 for all integers.  It's the remainder when you divide something by 1.  What were you really trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a simple `if`-`else` will do:

```
if (me.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY) && me.getClickCount() % 2 == 0) {
    bp.setPrefSize(480, 280);
    bp.setMaxSize(480, 280);
} else {
    bp.setPrefSize(320, 180);
    bp.setMaxSize(320, 180);
}
```

I think a better alternative, however, would be to have an `isExpanded` boolean field that you make use of in `handle`:

```
if (me.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY) && isExpanded) {
    // shrink:
    bp.setPrefSize(320, 180);
    bp.setMaxSize(320, 180);
    isExpanded = false;
} else {
    // expand:
    bp.setPrefSize(480, 280);
    bp.setMaxSize(480, 280);
    isExpanded = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to track state.  Not familiar with JavaFX but assuming bp's class is something you can edit, I'd update it to the following:

```
class BP{
    public boolean expanded = false; //this should be true if default state is expanded

    public void toggleExpanded(){
        if(expanded){
            this.setPrefSize(480, 280);
            this.setMaxSize(480, 280);
        }else{
            this.setPrefSize(320, 180);
            this.setMaxSize(320, 180);
        }
    }

    //rest of BP class
}
```

and then have your listener as follows:

```
    bp.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {

            if (me.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
                bp.toggleExpanded();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`MouseEvent.getClickCount`() returns the number of clicks on a small region over a small time interval as the documentation says. You need to store the state (normal or expanded) in a variable and toggle size and state accordingly.